# Should Reduce give all cases when $\sqrt{x y} = \sqrt x \sqrt y$?

Tags: equation-solving

My understanding is that `Reduce` gives all conditions (using or) where the input is true.

Now,  $\sqrt{xy} = \sqrt x \sqrt y $, where $x,y$ are **real**, under the following three conditions/cases

$$
\begin{align*}
x\geq 0,y\geq0\\
x\geq0,y\leq0\\
x\leq0,y\geq 0 \\
\end{align*}
$$

but not when $x<0,y<0$

This is verified by doing

```
ClearAll[x,y]
Assuming[Element[{x,y},Reals]&&x>= 0&&y<= 0,Simplify[ Sqrt[x*y] - Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]]]
Assuming[Element[{x,y},Reals]&&x<= 0&&y>= 0,Simplify[ Sqrt[x*y] - Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]]]
Assuming[Element[{x,y},Reals]&&x<= 0&&y>= 0,Simplify[ Sqrt[x*y] - Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]]]
Assuming[Element[{x,y},Reals]&&x<= 0&&y<=  0,Simplify[ Sqrt[x*y] - Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Then why does

```
 Reduce[ Sqrt[x*y] - Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y]==0,{x,y},Reals]
```

Give only one of the 3 cases above?

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is my understanding of `Reduce` wrong or should `Reduce` have given the other two cases?

V 12 on windows.

Comment: I think I read somewhere that specifying `Reals` makes it assume that subexpressions like `Sqrt[x]` are real too, excluding the 2 other cases.

Comment: @Coolwater I read the doc before, and it says (3rd point)  `assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities 
are real, while all other quantities are complex` but I only have `x,y` in there, so adding `Real` seems OK to me, since I want `x,y` to be reals?  But I just tried it without using `Real` and it did not given me the other 2 cases, even though the answer is more complicated now. So I am confused on this, that is why I asked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Coolwater says in his comment, using the domain specification [`Reals`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals) means that all function *values* are constrained to be real. Clearly `Sqrt[x]` is not real when $x<0$. Instead, constrain `x` and `y` to be real using [`Element`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element):

```
Reduce[Sqrt[x y] - Sqrt[x] Sqrt[y] == 0 && (x|y) ∈ Reals, {x,y}] //Simplify
```

> (y ∈ Reals && x > 0) || x == 0 || (x <= 0 && y >= 0)

Comment: I think then the help is really a little confusing and could be better written? it clearly says  `assumes by default that quantities appearing algebraically in inequalities are real, while all other quantities are complex`  and next point it says `restricts all variables and parameters to belong to the domain`. This is first time I see something about functions values vs. the variable themselves. But will try to read help again few more times :)

Comment: @Nasser See this [line](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce#26975) of the documentation. The next line also.

Comment: To avoid complex function values, specifying the domain as `Reals` is equivalent to requiring that all of the arguments to `Sqrt` must be nonnegative. 

`Reduce[eqn, {x, y}, Reals] == 
 Simplify[And @@ 
   Cases[Sqrt[x*y] == Sqrt[x]*Sqrt[y], Sqrt[z_] :> (z >= 0), Infinity]]` evaluates to 

`True`